# Array is blank when I go to make a table in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

So when I do a print of the 2 arrays in the get data function, it has the values I want, however, when I go to make the tableview, the count is zero and both arrays are empty. I have been trying to solve this for the last few hours and have also tried NSArrays.

```
var nameArray = [String]()
var textArray = [String]()

var urlStart = "https://api.deckbrew.com/mtg/cards?"


@IBOutlet weak var cardTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var info: UITextView!

class Card: Mappable {
    var name: String?
    var store_url: String?
    var text: String?
    required init?(_ map: Map) {
    }
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        name <- map["name"]
        store_url <- map["store_url"]
        text <- map["text"]
    }
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    func getData()
    self.tableView.reloadData()

    }


func getData() {

    let myURLString = "https://api.deckbrew.com/mtg/cards/typeahead?q=sele"
    let myURL = NSURL(string: myURLString)!

    var myCardsArray = [Card]()



    let mySession = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())
    let myDataTask = mySession.dataTaskWithURL(myURL) { (data, response, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            print("There was error with the task")
            return
        }
        do {
            let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)
            for someCard in jsonData as! NSArray{
                let card = Mapper<Card>().map(someCard)
                myCardsArray.append(card!)

                self.nameArray.append(card!.name!)
                self.textArray.append(card!.text!)

            }
        } catch {
            print("There was an error")
        }
    }

    myDataTask.resume()
}



override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
   return nameArray.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell : TableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Card") as! TableViewCell

    cell.cardTitle.text = nameArray[indexPath.row] as! String
   cell.cardInfo.text = textArray[indexPath.row] as! String

    return cell as TableViewCell
}




override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
```

}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you getting data with async methods, you shold reload your table view here:

```
 do {
            let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)
            for someCard in jsonData as! NSArray{
                let card = Mapper<Card>().map(someCard)
                myCardsArray.append(card!)

                self.nameArray.append(card!.name!)
                self.textArray.append(card!.text!)
//////// here
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()...) {
  self.tableView.reloadData()
}

            }
```

Comment: Sorry, I have to downvote because there's a severely issue with your suggested solution: in the completion handler - which does execute on a private dispatch queue - you are accessing and modifying `self.nameArray` and `self.textArray`. These are also accessed concurrently in the main thread which results in a data race. The app may crash when it is updating the arrays and when UIKit is simultaneously accessing the same array, for example when scrolling.@SagarGovani.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper in his case not and it's proper way to reload interface in main thread. Show me the right way instead of just downvoting

Answer (score 0):

The keys elements of `getData` run in a different thread (via `NSURLSession`).

So, when the table is populated by the `reloadData` in `viewDidLoad`, the array is probably still empty.  You may want to consider either refreshing the table at the end of `NSURLSession`'s closure (which *might* appear slow) or use another method to make sure that the array is populated before the `reloadData`.